# Why is my mongodb aggregation count being returned as a decimal?

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

The following query

```
db.getCollection("xyzCollection").aggregate(
    [
     { $match:
           { "startDate": { $gte: ISODate("2021-01-21T00:00:00.000+0000") } , "markets": { $exists: true }} 
     },
     { $group: 
           { _id: "$sportName" , "count": { $sum: 1 } }
     },
    ]
)
```

returns the following output:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "Ice Hockey", 
    "count" : 138.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : "Basketball", 
    "count" : 141.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : "Cricket", 
    "count" : 14.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : "Volleyball", 
    "count" : 32.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : "Football", 
    "count" : 685.0
}
```

Why is this?  And how can I make it return an int?  I'm using Studio 3T 2020.10.1 to execute the query.  I have already tried using $toInt (wrapping the "1" or wrapping the " { $sum: 1 } ") but as expected it didn't work - bad syntax.

Thanks.

Comment: can you run `explain()` and paste in the output

Comment: See [Data Types in the mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/index.html#numberdecimal): *The mongo shell treats all numbers as floating-point values by default.* `$toInt` should work, how did you make it?

Comment: was that answer helpful? could you approve/upvote?

Comment: Not really helpful in my case because as stated in the documentation $toInt is "New in version 4.0."  I tried and as expected (given I am not on 4.0 - from memory I am on 3.7) it didn't parse.

Answer (score 2):

It will return `int`

[Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ccsNcMfICin)

You could use `$toInt` in `$project` pipeline.

```
{
 $project: {
   sum: {$toInt :"$count" } 
 } 
}
```

[sample](https://mongoplayground.net/p/a3BuZzkUzhI)

I think it's due to Robo3t/Studio3t

Thanks @wernfried for the [reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/index.html#numberdecimal) to justify the behaviour.

Comment: If you try $group and $sum:1 it will do also. to me it's something else

Comment: I think it's due to robo3t/studio3t

Comment: yeah, also, the OP is not trying to sum `$count`. If you mean adding a stage just for that, then is a crime...

Answer (score 1):

If your query is executed by a javascript runtime (which is what usage of `ISODate` suggests since this is not an MQL construct), the (same) runtime that is rendering your results only has one numeric type and it's a floating point type.

Use a tool written in/utilizing another language that supports integer types.